# Query database for items using different Ids for the same object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

So I'm trying to get all the 'UserPhotos' where their 'userId' == 'FollowerId', I get a problem when there is more than one 'FollowerId', I need to know how to make it work for a list of 'followerIds' so users can get back the 'UserPhotos' of all of the 'Users' they are following

```
    [HttpGet("u/{username}")]
    public async Task<IQueryable> GetSpecificFeed(string username)
    {
        var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == username);
        // Follower is the user that is being followed
        // Following is the user that is doing the following (so the current logged in user)

        var userId = user.Id;
        // This bit works and returns the correct userId

        var followerIds = _context.Follows.Where(x => x.FollowerId == userId);
        // This should return all of the 'FollowerIds' that the current user is following
        // This however doesn't do that, it just throws this error:
        // SQLite Error 1: 'no such column: x.UserId' (I don't know why)

        var feed = _context.UserPhotos.Where(x => x.UserId == userId);
        // This currently returns all of the 'UserPhotos' if their 'UserId' is equal to the 'UserId' 
        // (which is the id of the user that is logged in) -> This isn't what I want it to do
        // Once the 'followerIds' return the correct thing, it should then get the userPhotos where
        // The UserId == followerIds (followerIds will be an array, so it will have to check through
        // multiple values to get the whole 'feed'

        return feed;
    }
```

So this is what I cant figure out

1. How to get the FollowerIds (as an array (I think they need to be an array but I'm not sure))
2. How to get the UserPhotos when the 'userId' has multiple values

(p.s. I'm not sure if the title is good, let me know if I should change it)

[EDIT]

This is the follows class

```
 public class Follow
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int FollowingId { get; set; }
        // user that is following

        public int FollowerId { get; set; }
        // user that is being followed
    }
```

User class (I removed properties that aren't relevant in this example)

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserPhoto> UserPhotos { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Follow> Follows { get; set; }
    }
```

userPhotos class (I removed properties that aren't relevant in this example)

```
public class UserPhoto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string photoUrl { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code that shows how it should work but it doesn't (this shows what I'm trying to accomplish)

```
    [HttpGet("u/{username}")]
    public async Task<IQueryable> GetSpecificFeed(string username)
    {
        var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == username);
        // Follower is the user that is being followed
        // Following is the user that is doing the following (so the current logged in user)

        var userId = user.Id;

        var photos = _context.UserPhotos;

        var followerIds = _context.Follows.Where(x => x.FollowerId == userId);
        // Get all of the userIds of the users that the currentUser is 
        // following and put them into 'followerIds'

        var feeds = photos.Where(x => x.UserId == followerIds);
        // Search 'photos' for where the 'userId (the id of the user who 
        //created it)' matches the 'followersIds'

        return feeds ;
    }
```

Comment: the exception of 'no such column' is related to the model declaration. Try to investigate The Follow class and make sure about its relationships.

Comment: I've done that and I have added relationships between them but cant see what I've done wrong, I've edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the following code:

```
    [HttpGet("u/{username}")]
    public async Task<IQueryable> GetSpecificFeed(string username)
    {
        var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == username);
        var userId = user.Id;
        var photos = _context.UserPhotos;
        var followerIds = _context.Follows.Where(x => x.FollowerId == userId).Select(x => x.FollowingId).ToList();
        var feeds = _context.UserPhotos.Where(x => followerIds.Contains(x.UserId));
        return feeds;
    }
```

Comment: This is great thanks, I do have a question though. You put 'contains', doesn't; that mean that it could return the wrong results, e.g. if the followersIds contain '1', couldn't it get confused and return the wrong results because the followerId includes '1', so it could return results with a followerId of '10' (or any number with 1 inside of it) aswell

Comment: @chumberjosh,you don’t need to worry at all. The followerIds returns `a list int collection ` composed of different ids. Contains here is to judge whether the current x.UserId is equal to one of the followerIds data collection. It is used as `int` data to judge whether they are equal. Instead of determining whether a character is included in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You should fire sql query first. You may use ToList() for that purpose in your case.

```
[HttpGet("u/{username}")]
public async Task<IQueryable> GetSpecificFeed(string username)
{
    var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == username);

    var userId = user.Id;

    var followerIds = _context.Follows.Where(x => x.FollowerId == userId).ToList();

    var feeds = _context.UserPhotos.Where(x => followerIds.Contains( x.UserId ));

    return feeds;
 }
```